# LISP SICP Video Lecture 2a Average Damp Question

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

In the following code, I am trying to understand how the variable `whatami` gets its value.  In following the logic, I see that the procedure `(lambda (y) (/ x y))` is the parameter that I am passing to the method `average-damp`, and is represented within that method as the variable `f`.  It seems as though `(/ x y)` and `(average (f whatami) whatami)` need to be executed, but I can't figure out the order of execution.  Any help is appreciated.

```
(define (average x y)
  (/ (+ x y) 2))

(define (fixed-point f start)
  (define tolerance 0.00001)
  (define (close-enuf? u v)
    (< (abs (- u v)) tolerance))
  (define (iter old new)
    (if (close-enuf? old new)
        new
        (iter new (f new))))
  (iter start (f start)))

(define average-damp
  (lambda (f)
    (lambda (whatami) (average (f whatami) whatami))))

; square root with average damping
(define (_sqrt x)
  (fixed-point
   (average-damp (lambda (y) (/ x y)))
   1))

(_sqrt 4.0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `average-damp` procedure takes a procedure as its argument and returns a procedure as its value. When given a procedure that takes one argument, `average-damp` returns another procedure that computes the average of the values before and after applying the original function `f` to its argument.  It's inside the `fixed-point` procedure where that returned function is applied (iteratively).

So the `average-damp` procedure doesn't execute either `(/ x y)` or `(average(f whatami) whatami)` at all, it just uses the function passed to it to create a new function that it returns.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I'm still a little unsure of how the variable whatami gets its value.  I see that average-damp is a procedure that takes a procedure and returns a procedure.  However, within the body of average-damp, it is somehow averaging two values.  --  If I may ask from a different direction... In the fixed-point method, the parameter f is the returned procedure of average-damp correct?  Hmm, so then whatami in the first iter is 1.  Average-damp is really only used that very first time in _sqrt.  Haha, I think I just got it!  Thanks!!

Comment: @Benjamin: Yes, that's exactly right.  The `fixed-point` procedure is only called once and it does not call itself recursively, so the result function of `average-damp` is only created one time.  The returned function is called iteratively, so the value of `whatami` changes, but it does start out as 1, the first value passed to `fixed-point` in your `_sqrt` procedure.